# textsuperscript command within glossaries fails

Tags: errors, subscripts

So I am trying to add a term to glossaries which is ED\textsubscript{50} so I have the following code:

```latex
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{acro}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ED\textsubscript{50}}{ED\textsubscript{50}}{Median effective dose}

\begin{document}

  \gls{ED\textsubscript{50}}

  \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

And I get:

This document could not be compiled.

If I remove the `\textsubscript` everything works fine, but I need it in there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `\newacronym` should be a mnemonic label and should not contain commands.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ED50}{ED\textsubscript{50}}{Median effective dose}

\begin{document}

\gls{ED50}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

#### Page 1

[image]

#### Page 2

[image]